# Fectching validation rule for specific object

Tags: salesforce1-app, metadata-api

So i am trying to fetch validation rule for a specific object, is  there any API call via which i can achieve the same ?

Already done with fetching validation rule for all objects via

> listMetadata(ListMetadataQuery[] queries, double asOfVersion)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the particular validation rules for an object by fetching the object definition with readMetaData. You have to fetch the complete object. It's not possible to get only the validation rules.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_readMetadata.htm

Use metadatatype 'CustomObject'. You will get back a CustomObject with e.g. the 'fields' child objects but also 'validationRules'.